# Rails - dynamic record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a record `Portfolio` which has 3 attributes `start_date`, `end_date` and `return`.

When creating a new `Portfolio`, I want the user to fill in the first two attributes. Then, I want to query the database and compute the bounds for the `return` attribute(which is a `float`). Then, I want to display the fill-in field for `return`.

How can I do this?

Comment: use `ajax`, tried something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rename the `return` variable to something else (return_date maybe) as return is a built in function.

You can use a 'callback' to 'do stuff' before/after doing something with an Active Record object.
Check this out for more details on callbacks in general:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

In your case, assuming you do not want to save a record without a return_date (a return_date of null), you may want to compute the return date before validation of the record as so,

```
validates :return_date, presence: true
before_validation :compute_return_date

def compute_return
  return_date = self.end_date - self.start_date
end
```

If you don't care about return_date being null, you can register the callback on `before_save` instead of `before_validation`.

This works because a record is first validated, then it is saved. I suggest going with the before_validation as it's best practice not to stick null's into rails db's if you do not have to.